# Uninitialized std::string within a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I am a bit perplexed.   I am creating a custom "Variant" class, but am running into a strange issue with std::string member.

When I try to assign it from another Variant instance, I get an exception that the string is a bad pointer.    I am not sure I understand why this would happen because the string should be an instance when the class is constructed.

Here is my code:

```
class Variant : ObjectBase {
public:
    Variant() {};
    Variant(const Value& node) { parse(node); };

    ValueType Type = ValueType::Unknown;

    Variant& operator= (bool value)
    { Type = ValueType::Boolean; value_.vBool = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (std::string value)
    { Type = ValueType::String; value_string_ = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (double value)
    { Type = ValueType::Double; value_.vDouble = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (int32_t value)
    { Type = ValueType::Int32; value_.vInt32 = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (int64_t value)
    { Type = ValueType::Int64; value_.vInt64 = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (uint32_t value)
    { Type = ValueType::Uint32; value_.vUint32 = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (uint64_t value)
    { Type = ValueType::Uint64; value_.vUint64 = value; return *this; };
    Variant& operator= (const Value& node) { parse(node); };
private:
    union Any {
        int32_t vInt32;
        int64_t vInt64;
        double vDouble;
        bool vBool;
        uint32_t vUint32;
        uint64_t vUint64;
        Any() : vDouble(0) {};
    } value_;

    std::string value_string_;
};
```

The exception occurs when I do this:

```
Variant v1 = "Hello";
Variant v2 = v1;   // <--- Here is where it occurs
```

Now, if I create a manual = operator overload, I can see that v2 value is a bad pointer, but I am not sure why.   Here is my overload:

```
Variant& operator= (const Variant value) {
    value_ = value.value_;
    value_string_ = value.value_string_;
    Type = value.Type;
    return *this;
}
```

Maybe I am tired or something, but it is not obvious to me what am I missing here.

Comment: `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    Variant& operator= (const Value& node) { parse(node); };`

Comment: `error: no viable conversion from 'const char [6]' to 'Variant'
    Variant v1 = "Hello";`  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c16693de7a97ab9)

Comment: What if you define an assignment operator for `char*`?

Comment: Can you include ` ObjectBase` and your `ValueType` enum?

Comment: Your code never invokes any of your assignment operators: both `Variant v1 = "Hello";` and `Variant v2 = v1;` invoke constructors. The former in particular, if it compiles at all, invokes `Variant(Value("Hello"))`. So, what's `Value`, what constructors does it have, and what does `parse()` do?

Comment: Parse is irrelevant...not being used.   The problem actually (as I trace deeper into it), turns out to be the line `value_string_ = value.value_string_` value.value_string_ is uninitialized and it crashes when trying to access the value_string_ variable on the rhs.   So what this tells me is that if you define a variable `std::string x` and `std::string y` and then state `x = y`, it would crash unless y was initialized with some string value.   I thought that std::string means to create an instance.  Why would it crash?

Comment: @user3072517: Assigning a valid string wouldn't crash. Something in your code has destroyed or corrupted one of the strings (or perhaps some other string in the mysterious base class, or elsewhere). Please post enough code (preferably as a [self contained test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) for us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code compiles at all (which is not clear, as complete code has not been given) then the statements

```
Variant v1 = "Hello";
Variant v2 = v1;
```

invoke constructors, not assignment operators.

In the first, since `Variant` does not supply a constructor that accepts a string, this means `Value` does, and an implicit conversion to `Value` is being done before invoking the constructor for `Variant`.   The problem is therefore either in the constructor for `Value`, or in working of the parse()` function.   Neither of those have been shown though.

The second statement invokes the compiler-generated copy constructor.  Which, if the preceding construction has not worked as required, will also introduce problems.

Comment: It seems that this is a problem with vs2013.   I did not see this problem occuring in gcc.    This seems to work http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a6916cfc47e48ef

But in VS, I actually had to do this: `if( value.Type == ValueType::String)    value_string_ = value.value_string_;`